# Downloading a file and playing it with videoplayer in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayer

Looking to implement the following logic with xcode:
1) Download a File === OK for me and is executing as an asynchronous operation.
2) After that i want to run it with the movie player:
3) A sample code which i tried is shown below. It does not wait for the download to finish. Can any one suggest an alternate way of doing these or modifications to this code? I does not want to wait using timers.

```
DowloadFilesManager * mydw =[[DowloadFilesManager alloc] init];
[mydw downloadURL:@"http://localhost/videos/video3x.mov" destPath:anObj.uRL];
while([mydw downLoadStatus])
{
    NSLog(@"Downloading finished);
    [videoPlayer1 setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/varunisac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/851B4382-AF7E-4653-B28F-8F0707AC5D45/Documents/SalesAppFolder/video3x.mov"]];
    [videoPlayer1 prepareToPlay];
    [videoPlayer1 play];
}
```

Comment: Just try to play your stream directly to MPMoviePlayer

Comment: thank you anish for the quick reply  but i want to play the offline file  stored.!!

Comment: You can do it by downloading the movie..
I will post code in answer..

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, not a movie player. This question appears to have nothing to do with use of an IDE.

Comment: see in answers I posted..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932542/downloading-a-file-and-playing-it-with-videoplayer-in-ios/21932937#21932937
@VARUNISAC

Answer (score 0):

How do you download your file? Are you using `NSURLDownload`? You have to implement `NSURLDownloadDelegate` somewhere (probably in one of your view controllers) and wait for the method `downloadDidFinish:` to be called. In that method you run your code above to start playback.

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatch_sync method for downloading video file.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    DowloadFilesManager * mydw =[[DowloadFilesManager alloc] init];
    [mydw downloadURL:@"http://localhost/videos/video3x.mov" destPath:anObj.uRL];
});
while([mydw downLoadStatus])
{
   NSLog(@"Downloading finished);
   [videoPlayer1 setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/Users/varunisac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/851B4382-AF7E-4653-B28F-8F0707AC5D45/Documents/SalesAppFolder/video3x.mov"]];
   [videoPlayer1 prepareToPlay];
   [videoPlayer1 play];
}
```